# Is it correct that `any[never]` is of type `any`?

Tags: typescript, types, type-systems

From `unknown` to tuples, to object, number... If you access them with `[never]` it is equal to `never`. So why would `any[never]` behave differently? Is the following consistent, why?

```
type test0 = number[never] // never
type test1 = object[never] // never
type test2 = string[never] // string?
type test3 = any[never]    // any?

type test4 = number[][never] // number
type test5 = object[][never] // object
type test6 = string[][never] // string
type test7 = any[][never]    // any
type test8 = {}[][never]     // {}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's consistent. `never` is a sub-type of all types. So it can be assigned to any other type. So if we can index with `never` without compiler errors:

```
declare let o: never;
declare let arr: any[];
arr[o] // not error, any
```

The rest is just a matter of what can be indexed. `number` and `object` have no index signatures, so the result it `never`. `string` is indexable and the result is a `string` so `string[never]` is `string`. `any` is universally indexable, and the result is `any` so `any[never]` is `any`.

For arrays indexing with `never` as we saw above is possible and will give us the item type, so those results are consistent.

Comment: It's kind of strange though. I would think that accessing a part that is `never` would consistently return something that can never be accessed, that is to say `never`. I don't find this consistent and creates recursive-logic hiccups when traversing with recursive types. Which I fix by using: 
`type At<O, K extends (string | number | symbol)> = K extends keyof O ? O[K] : never`
That kind of shows that there is an inconsistency. What do you think?

Comment: @pirix-gh I think that is a common misconception about `never`, one that I shared at  first, to view it as a universal error type. It's not. It's just the subtype of all types, meaning you can never create an instance of it (hence it's name) but since it is the subtype of all types it also means its a universal source, so you can take a reference of type `never` and assign it to a reference of any other type.  This behavior is also reflected in these index access types.